# MVVM: how model can use inotifypropertychanged to notify viewmodel of changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I need Model to notify ViewModel if any property is changed, because I need to collect the changed model instances in a collection for further processing, also to enable and disable command buttons in the viewmodel.
So I've used ModelBase abstract class and added  HasChanges property which I can test against in the viewmodel and catch the changed models.But it is not working and I don't know what i'm missing.

```
public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected ModelBase()
    {
    }

    private bool _hasChanges;
    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get
        { 
            return _hasChanges;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_hasChanges != value)
            {
                _hasChanges = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("HasChanges");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        HasChanges = true;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The Model is wrapped inside the ViewModel and bound to the View which is a `DataGrid`:

```
private Model_selectedModel;

public Mode SelectedModel
{
    get 
    {
        return _selectedModel; 
    }

    set
    {
        if (_selectedModel != value)
        {
            _selectedModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your class and it's okay. I think the point is a typo here:

```
private Model_selectedModel;

public Mode SelectedModel
{
    get 
    {
        return _selectedModel; 
    }

    set
    {
        if (_selectedModel != value)
        {
            _selectedModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
        }
    }
}
```

There should be **`RaisePropertyChanged`** instead of *`NotifyPropertyChanged`*.

Below it's my test:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="TestUpdatePropertyChanged.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TestUpdatePropertyChanged"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:TestViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="25" Text="{Binding Path=TestString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <Button Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var testData = this.DataContext as TestViewModel;

        testData.TestString = "Yay, it's change!";

        if (testData.HasChanges == true) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It's Change!");
        }
    }
}

public class TestViewModel : ModelBase 
{
   private string _testString = "test";

    public string TestString
    {
        get { return _testString; }

        set
        {
            if (_testString != value)
            {
                _testString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TestString");
            }
        }
    }
} 

public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected ModelBase()
    {
    }

    private bool _hasChanges;
    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get
        { 
            return _hasChanges;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_hasChanges != value)
            {
                _hasChanges = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("HasChanges");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        HasChanges = true;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anatoily : sorry for not being totally clear, its my Model that inherits ModelBase. My ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Hussein: You need to determine the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for Model, or for `ViewModel` - not for both. Or that both inherit from Modelbase (you need his just to name differently, for example: `NotificationObject`).